# Quarkus - specify own hibernate dialect to use Vlad Mihalcea's Json Hibernate Extension

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am currently trying to use some json types in my database.

I tried as per this article:

https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-server-json-hibernate/

After including this I got the following excetion:

```
2021-07-13 11:08:07,235 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlAlterStrings(Table.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:327)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:58)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I then tried to create my own dialect as per this article:

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/

but I still get the same excetion. I tried adding my own class to the dialect property in the application properties. But this didn't seem to do the trick.

Is there a way to configure this with quarkus? I am concerned, that I really cannot do it, as there is a disclaimer at the property concerning its limitation.

Edit: I intially fixed it, because I removed the auto generation of the database schema. I get this error now again, after I added quarkus-quartz with the DB storage of triggers (Cluster mode with quarkus.quartz.store-type=JDBC_TX). The application tries to update the trigger in the database (changed schedule time) and throws this error.

I have added the following class:

```
package emilfrey.backend;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeBinaryType;
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

public class SQLServer2012JsonDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {
    public SQLServer2012JsonDialect(){
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());

    }
}
```

and added the following property in the application.properties

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect = somepackage.backend.SQLServer2012JsonDialect
```

The error still persists. I guess it has something to do with the availablity of that new class and its loading. But I am not sure. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Thank you already.

Comment: There's a Quarkus extension for (or actually a port of) the JSON Hibernate types: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-hibernate-types

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this extension. But the root cause was something different. The issue is during creation of the database. The column cannot be created automatically by hibernate - neither by the quarkus internal one nor the official one by vlad mihalcea. it seems I don't need the quarkus wrapper at all for it to just work for saving and loading. Not sure about the native querys though. I haven't come that far. :)

Comment: Did you, in your dialect implementation (you need a custom one apparently), configure a SQL type name for the `Types.OTHER` code by using `registerColumnType(Types.OTHER, "json")` in the constructor?

Comment: I added the following class and added it to the application properties. 
`
public class SQLServer2012JsonDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {
    public SQLServer2012JsonDialect(){
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());

    }
}

quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect =somename.backend.SQLServer2012JsonDialect

`
It seems it is connected to native query some quarkus plugins like quartz are doing. If I remove these dependencies and use only my application code it works like a charm without any additional  Dialect Class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fixing this when schema generation is enabled.

But to anyone with this problem when schema generation is *disabled*, in Quarkus Dev mode, it's a bug that was fixed in Quarkus 2.4.1: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21122